# How to get self object name from self method in Python

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, self

I am trying to find a way to automatically print the object reference name with just a `print object`
To be more specific.
Lets say I have a class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def __str__(self):
        # return a string representation of A
        return "A contains " ...
    ...
```

Now whenever i create an object

```
test = A()
```

and I use the `print test` it will get something like (do not mind the dots)

```
A contains ...
```

What I want to achieve is to automatically print the object reference name instead of the class name:

```
test contains ...
```

The `self.__class__` or `self.__name__` wont work since it returns a weird string like `<class '__main__.A'>`.

How should `__str__` be implemented  to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Objects don't have names, they just have references.

Comment: are you trying to print the identifier of the variable your instance is bound to? if so, i don't think thats possible ( or wise ). consider an instance of class A that is not bound to any variable. what would you print then? or if it is bound to two or many variables? maybe you could pass a name for that object in the constructor and print that.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Daenyth Well each time i use a `print object` to just print itself and not its class

Comment: Why are you trying to print the object? What goal are you trying to accomplish by that

Comment: @Daenyth Simply put to print its self name instead of the class that the object inherited from. This could be useful in a list of objects. I was just stuck on this and i just wanted to ask here. 1 answer was deleted somehow, maybe the author changed his mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments on your question have stated, it is not possible and also unwise, consider something along the lines of the following approach instead:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cards = []
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} contains ...'.format(self.name)

>>> test = A('test')
>>> print test
test contains ...

>>> a = A('hello')
>>> print a
hello contains ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is exactly what I want to avoid, passing the reference name on instantiation. If this is the only solution then I guess what I asked is not possible :|

Answer (score 1):

I know I am replying too late but if anyone stumbles here like I do here is the solution:

```
type(self).__name__
```

your implementation would be:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cards = []
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} contains...'.format(type(self).__name__)
a=A('test')
print(a)
# A contains ...
```