# PyQt mousePressEvent returns widgetName?

Tags: widget, pyqt4

Today I have implemented my own widget based on QWidget and I added a mousePressEvent so whenever I create this widget, I can click inside and trigger an event. Now I would like that when I click it returns my widgetObjectName.
How could I do that ?

I ve seen that maybe I could get the mouse position and then use itemAt()
but it doesn't seem to work for QWidget...

Any simple way of doing that ?

Thx

Comment: When you post a question here. please post with more info and the code that you have tried so far. It'll be much helpful for the others to understand your problem well.

Comment: Unfortunately its not possible to get an objects name. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580236/how-to-get-self-object-name-from-self-method-in-python

Comment: `def mousePressEvent(self, event): print(self.objectName())`.